# Removing response headers when accessing images from S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, header, response

Can we remove response headers when we are accessing images stored on Amazon S3?

By default it is giving the following headers:
x-amz-id-2:
x-amz-request-id:
Server:

By default it is giving amazon related values for these headers. Is there any way to remove headers?

Answer (score 0):

Not without proxying the requests through some software you control that can strip the headers. Pretty sure Amazon has no user setting for that.